# Why isn't UICollectionViewLayout laying out the cells correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView that you can swipe horizontally. 6 images on each page. paging enabled. it looks great but for some reason when you swipe the page it takes the image that would be in the top right to the bottom of the first column. But as soon as the 2nd column on the page you are swiping to loads it moves back to the correct position.

Here is an image of what it looks like.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kbtb8cy99pernv/Screenshot%202014-09-13%2020.41.49.PNG?dl=0

(see there in the bottom right)

Here is the code

```
- (void)prepareLayout {

self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 2) , 251);
self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
self.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(129, 0, 140,0);
self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;


}



// indicate that we want to redraw as we scroll
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return YES;
}
```